# Adding Compression to Images before sending to server to a Rails Active Storage application with/wo Direct Upload and Canvas/Compress.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, image-compression

I have already worked with Active Storage and Direct Uploads. I have installed ActiveStorage and and created the database so there is no problem with adding images. I have added this to my model:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

and putting the form field in the view as such:

```
<%= f.file_field :images, accept:'image/*', class: "input-file" multiple %>
```

and adding this to my controller:

```
private
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:title, :content, images: [])
    end
```

Not sure if this will save me data (since most of the photos will probably be huge) but any suggestions on implementation would be great. I would like to get something like canvas compress using base64(again not sure if this is best)  and resize, convert to blob then upload or a javascript compress like compress.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress.js) working on the images so they would be compressed and sized on the user's side before being sent to the server thus reducing the amount of data being sent.

I found this code here which I'm not super certain about or how to integrate something like this because Javascript is not in my wheelhouse.

```
function compressImage (base64) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  const img = document.createElement('img')

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    img.onload = function () {
      let width = img.width
      let height = img.height
      const maxHeight = 200
      const maxWidth = 200

      if (width > height) {
        if (width > maxWidth) {
          height = Math.round((height *= maxWidth / width))
          width = maxWidth
        }
      } else {
        if (height > maxHeight) {
          width = Math.round((width *= maxHeight / height))
          height = maxHeight
        }
      }
      canvas.width = width
      canvas.height = height

      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)

      resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.7))
    }
    img.onerror = function (err) {
      reject(err)
    }
    img.src = base64
  })
}
```

Basically I'm asking a two part question. If my users will be uploading many photos (display res isn't  necessary to be kept super high) will using canvas compress with base64 then return the image as a blob be the best use or just sticking with direct upload (rails js) and not bother with compressing the image? 2nd Part is how would I go about implementing this if that is a good idea? Many sites do this already where maintaining the original photo size is not necessary.